# Create custom UIBarButtomItem in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

I need to make custom "Settings" button in navigation bar.
But, unfortunately, I was unable to make in in storyboard editor correctly.
I need to see only my picture, no button rectangle.

[image]

Is there are a way to make with kind of button correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code in the ViewController `-viewDidLoad` method:

for the left bar button:

```
UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarMapBtn.png"];
[leftButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
```

or for the right bar button:

```
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarMapBtn.png"];
[rightButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton];
```

There's no need to add a BarButtonItem to your view in the xib or storyboard.

Here's what it could look like:

[image]